# how to decode xml data into a human readable format

Tags: xml

I have some xml files which have been used as personal data files in an astrological application.

The appliction does not exists more, but I still need the data. Opening the xml I have the following:

```
<BirthDate>2442260.7083333</BirthDate>
```

or

```
<BirthDate>2436617.0375000</BirthDate>
```

in this case real date is 17.02.1959. 12:54 (12:54 is the birthtime).

or

```
<BirthDate>2446904.4652778</BirthDate>
```

in this case real date is 18.04.1987. 23:10 (23:10 is the birthtime).

Is there a way to decode this and get the date/time in a readable format?

Comment: Are you actually asking about XML or are you trying to work out how that number relates to a date?

Comment: What is the date corresponding to that number?  With that information we could figure out how it is encoded.

Comment: @JimGarrison, pls see the update of my post.

Comment: That helps but the epoch makes no sense.  Can you provide a second value and its corresponding date?

Comment: @JimGarrison, I added one more date/time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding method is indeed based on days (the integer part) and fractions of days (the decimal part), but the epoch is about 6611 years in the past.

The simplest way to decode these dates/times is to use Excel, with an adjustment for the epoch (zero point).  The adjustment is -2415019 days.

Thus if you place the formula

```
=2436617.0375-2415019
```

in a cell and format as date/time you get

```
2/17/59 00:54
```

For the other value the formula

```
=2446904.4652778-2415019
```

gives the date

```
4/18/87 11:10
```

so I suspect the value you gave of 23:10 is a typo.

Note that calculating the epoch date (when in the past the zero point was) is meaningless as no modern calendars were in use at the time.  You could extrapolate but you'd have to pick a calendar (Julian vs Gregorian or something else) and whatever you come up with (around 4595 BC) won't be useful for anything.

Here's a screenshot of a sample Excel worksheet

[image]

The first column is your values, the second is the value adjusted with the epoch offset, and the third is the second column formatted as a date/time.

Excel uses `12/31/1899 00:00` as its epoch; that is, the value zero renders in Excel as `1/0/1900` (which is itself weird) and the value `1` gives `1/1/1900`.  If you want to do the conversion in code you can use this knowledge to adjust the offset for whatever programming library you are using.

Comment: thanks a lot for your efforts. I think problem will be solved this way (using excel).

Answer (score -2):

This isn't actually an XML question, but one of interpreting a weird (and probably undocumented) date representation. The fractional part of the number is 17/24, which indicates that it probably means 5 PM on a given date.
However, when we interpret the part before the decimal point as a day number, it would be based on a date about 6687 years in the past. That does not seem to make much sense...

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: I was unsure - it answers at least part of the question (how to approach decoding this number).

Comment: You should await clarification from the OP.  All we need is a corresponding date to calculate the likely epoch and encoding.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner, please see the update of my post.